# How to check if entered value is integer and format input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input field that should only allow integer values. Also, the maximum number of characters is ten including dash `-`. While user is entering value the format should be applied. For example if user enters `004546671`. The value should look like this in the input field: `00-4546671`. While user is entering values int he input field if they try to enter alphabetic character or anything else other then an integer that value should not be allowed. Here is example of the input field:

```js
$("#sys_id").on("keypress", function() {
  var inputFld = $(this);
  
  if( inputFld.val() ) {
    console.log(inputFld.val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="sys_id" id="sys_id" maxlength="10" placeholder="00-0000000">
```

Is there a way to prevent other values than integers to be entered? Also, how to apply format `00-0000000`?

Comment: `00-0000000` is not an integer

Comment: Take a look to the [JQuery Inputmask Plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask), I have used that one on a project, and you can make aliases and extensions. But, i'm sure there are others with same features too.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use native input validation? You really just need a regex to validate that the numbers entered are integers and that they are seperated by a hyphen. So, allow 2 digits, hyphen, 7 digits.

*I am not regex expert, so this is a very basic example and may not cover all the cases you need to cover*

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{2}-\d{7}" />
```

[Input Patterns](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)